# I am making a simple project in python 3 about multiplication tables but I am getting syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

This is the code:

```
num = int(input("Please enter your number: "))

for i in range(1,11)
print(num, "×", i ,"=", num*i)
```

This is the error it gives me:

```
File "table.py", line 3
    for i in range(1,11)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` and indentation.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Seems like you're missing some basic syntax rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of loops, if-statements and some other python blocks of code require ":" at the end of the line and a tab-indented new block of code.

The correct code for your example would be:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(num, "x", i, "=", num*i)
```

What I am talking about is:

```
if True:
    print("In true statement")
    print("The next line of indented block")
else:
    print("Not in the True statement")
    print("I would never get here")
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```py
for i in range(1,11):
    print(num, "x", i, "=", num*i)
```

it seem like you forgot the `:` at the end of the for loop and the indentation in the following line.